# DocuSign how to customize name and company for each envelope without create users?

Tags: docusignapi

Is that possible to customize name and company name for each envelope without create all users? or even just hide it?

If this is not possible, what is the recommendations for the following scenario?

- We have 5,000 users, they are from different companies(different email domain)
- User purchase points on our system, and they use points to buy eSign envelope
- We don't want to create 5,000 users under our DocuSign account (not only adding them, we also don't want them to have account to login to DocuSign and create envelope without pay us.
- We like to show their name and company in highlight area below
- We are OK the email send to the singer is from DocuSign

[image: Highlight Area]

Answer (score 0):

What you show is the name and company of the sender, the account holder, the person who initiated the request to sign. Not the signer, the person who needs to act on it. Hope this is clear.

You can change the name and company name of the sender/company account programmatically, and then send the next envelope.

However, if you want to do something like this, you won't be able to use bulk send, because it doesn't allow you to make the change between each envelope.

You can run a loop that does this:

1. Change name/company
2. Create envelope
3. Send envelope

Doing this 5000 times also has an issue with API limit (default to 3000/hour) so you will either have to throttle this or contact support to increase your limit

Changing the name of the account holder can be done like this:

Here is C# code for this:

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
// You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication method
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
UsersApi usersApi = new UsersApi(apiClient);
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
userProfile.UserDetails = new UserInformation();
userProfile.UserDetails.FirstName = "Inbar";
userProfile.UserDetails.LastName = "Gazit";
usersApi.UpdateProfile(accountId, userId, userProfile);
```

You can find all other langs and more details here - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-update-the-name-docusign-user

Comment: thanks for quick replay, the "loop" method will not work because when the singer click the link from the email, they always see the last updated user profile, we need show different name/company for each envelope .

Comment: Then you need 5000 accounts or 5000 users, no way around it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after contact DoucSign support.

No, there is no way you can change it direct. But you can edit "template" for the email, under "Settings > Brand", you can download current HTML templates for emails, edit, and upload back. You can use "DocuSign build-in token" inside template, so create custom fields, set value for each envelope, and reference in the template.